# C# application How to Remove "To Display The webpage againthe web browser needs to resend the information you've previously submitted ..." message

Tags: c#, browser

I have a c# application that has a browser and navigates to web pages. One of the web pages has multiple pages inside and for some reason when we programmatically hit next button it goes to home page.
while trying to find solution I noticed that if we refresh the page at the time this happens it will go to the page we want. But when I tried to automate this by adding browser.Refresh() it shows following message, 
how can I solve/Remove this? what changes I need to make? any line of code I can add to my C# code.

[image]

Comment: Could you post the code you're using? Are you using the `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` class?

Comment: Use two browsers.  One stays on the main page and one you use to navigate to other pages.   You are loosing the main page and the server is requiring you to login again.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb yes I am using System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.

Answer (score 0):

Till now the only solution I found is to Navigate again to webpage instead of Browser.Refresh() and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The web page you're looking at is the result of a POSTed form. If you have control over the web server, you should redirect after a successful POST to avoid processing the same data twice.